# How to center punctuation in vertical CJK text?

Tags: css, cjk, punctuation, vertical-text

I have a CJK (Chinese) text displayed vertically using CSS (`body { writing-mode: vertical-rl; }`). Unfortunately, punctuation is not centered by default:

[image: Chinese punctuation]

The full stops and commas are aligned to the top right, rather than the center. I get the same result in Firefox 65.0 and Chromium 71.0.

Is there an established method for centering the punctuation? I feel like I must be missing something obvious. The physical Chinese books I have are printed with centered punctuation, and yet reading the [W3C article on vertical text](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/) and the MDN CSS documentation turned up nothing on centering punctuation for vertical CJK texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the alignment of punctuation is influenced by the language attribute `lang`; in Chinese, for instance, it depends on whether the attribute value is plain `"zh"` or traditional `"zh-Hant"`.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Here is the HTML document I used to test it (I had to shorten the Chinese text to be allowed to post it inline):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Vertical Writing Punctuation</title>
    <style>
        body { writing-mode: vertical-rl; }
        .vertical-text { height: 9em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<div class="vertical-text" lang="zh">
「體也若有端」五字，張惠言謂為第二條之錯簡，孫從之。
</div>
<hr>
<div class="vertical-text" lang="zh-Hant">
「體也若有端」五字，張惠言謂為第二條之錯簡，孫從之。
</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, I have absolutely no idea about the meaning of the Chinese text I copied from a random site...

**UPDATE**:

According to [Best Practices for Chinese Layout – Bobby Tung](https://medium.com/@bobtung/best-practice-in-chinese-layout-f933aff1728f), it appears that Chinese punctuation gets centered only if the text is displayed in a *Traditional Chinese* font, regardless of the writing mode (horizontal or vertical).

Web browsers like Firefox or Safari respect the `lang` attribute and assign automatically an appropriate font for display; it seems, however, that Chrome ignores it. An extra :lang CSS selector is needed then...

Here is another test page with centered punctuation for both horizontal and vertical text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Centered Punctuation</title>
    <style>
        :lang(zh-Hant) { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, times, Heiti TC, PMingLiU, PMingLiu-ExtB, SimSun, SimSun-ExtB, HanaMinA, HanaMinB; }
        .horizontal-text { width: 9em; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; }
        .vertical-text { height: 9em; writing-mode: vertical-rl; }
    </style>
</head>
<body lang="zh-Hant">
<hr>
<div class="horizontal-text">
「體也若有端」五字，張惠言謂為第二條之錯簡，孫從之。
</div>
<hr>
<div class="vertical-text">
「體也若有端」五字，張惠言謂為第二條之錯簡，孫從之。
</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: the font stack for Traditional Chinese is the one used on the Chinese Text Project web site.

[image]

Comment: Trivia: the text you copied from is [墨經校釋 by 梁啟超](https://ctext.org/mo-jing-jiao-shi). It is a commentary on [Mozi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozi_(book)), a text from the [Warring States period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period) (475 - 221 BC). Also, the text in the question above is from [Mencius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mencius_(book)) (c. 300 BC).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will definitely read the Wikipedia pages. I remember now that the text comes indeed from the Chinese Text Project; actually, I have been using their [Character lookup dictionary](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en) as a reference for one of my Unihan-related utility apps. I do have a passion for Chinese characters in general, but I must confess that the only CJK language I'm familiar with is Japanese...